# How to retrieve and view data from a SQL Server using sqljdbc library in Android?

Tags: android, sql, sql-server

I am having troubles in "how to's" of connecting to a prepoppulated database which is being used by our ASP.NET application.

So, the problem is that I have used the sqljdbc4.jar library to try to connect to my database and during that all i get are the exceptions and I cant seem to find a solution about it. I would appreciate if someone could correct my code or give me some help regarding it. I cant seem to find the solution anywhere.

Below is the code which I am calling in the OnCreate block in the mainactivity in which I am currently getting a **os.NetworkOnMainThreadException**

```
 public void testDB() {
 TextView tv = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
 // Create a variable for the connection string.
 String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;" +
         "databaseName=CafeApp;user=Sunny;password=";
 String result = "Database connection success\n";

 // Declare the JDBC objects.
 Connection con = null;
 Statement stmt = null;
 ResultSet rs = null;
 ResultSetMetaData rsmd;

 try {
     // Establish the connection.
     Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
     con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);

     // Create and execute an SQL statement that returns some data.
     String SQL = "SELECT TOP 10 * FROM inventory.inventory_name";
     stmt = con.createStatement();
     rs = stmt.executeQuery(SQL);
     rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

     // Iterate through the data in the result set and display it.
     while (rs.next()) {
        // System.out.println(rs.getString(4) + " " + rs.getString(6));
         result += rsmd.getColumnName(1) + ": " + rs.getInt(1) + "\n";
         result += rsmd.getColumnName(2) + ": " + rs.getString(2) + "\n";
         result += rsmd.getColumnName(3) + ": " + rs.getInt(3) + "\n";

     }
     tv.setText(result);
 }

 // Handle any errors that may have occurred.
 catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
     tv.setText(e.toString());
 } finally {
     if (rs != null) try {
         rs.close();
     } catch(Exception e) {
     }
     if (stmt != null) try {
         stmt.close();
     } catch(Exception e) {
     }
     if (con != null) try {
         con.close();
     } catch(Exception e) {
     }
 }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use AsyncTask...
Because android doesn't allow any networking task on it's main thread.

just put this testDB() method on separate thread.

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                testDB()
            }
        }).start();
```

Comment: Or you can go with async task ... it's up to you

Comment: Can you guide me a bit about it? Any good tutorials or something handy?

Comment: It gave another exception.

Is there any other way to access and retrieve data from a sql database ??